# How to fire Ajax function with radiobutton click MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View made up of 3 Partial Views:

Partial View #1 is listing RadioButtons.  When I click a button I would like to send the resulting selection to the controller in order to update the Partial View #2 (which is a Telerik grid).  Then the selection in PV #2 will update Partial View #3 (another Telerik grid).

I am currently doing a Window.location to send selected values to the Controller which causes the Controller and ViewModel to be reloaded and lose state.  Other than losing the state, the flow works as I would like.

**Is there a way to do this in Ajax to where I do  not have to reload the Controller?**

I will spare you the Partial Views #2 & #3 of the Telerik grids.  If I can get the answer to how to get the radio button to call the Controller without a postback, I can apply the same to those Partial Views.

View:

```
    @model MyProject.ViewModel.MaterialsListVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Materials List";
}

<div>        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.Partial("MaterialTypeFilter")
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.Partial("MaterialsGrid")            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.Partial("ProjectMaterialsGrid")
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Partial View #1:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.MaterialsListVM

<div class="container">
   <h5>   @Html.Label("Material Type:  ", new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })</h5>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Material_Type.MaterialTypeList.Count; i++)
                {
            <span class="btn-group-sm">
                @Html.RadioButton("MatType", new { Model.Material_Type.MaterialTypeList[i].Name }, Model.Material_Type.MaterialTypeList[i].Selected, new { @onclick = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
                &nbsp;
                @Html.Label(Model.Material_Type.MaterialTypeList[i].Name)
            </span><br />
                }
            }

     </div>

<script>
        function CallChangefunc(value) {
            var selected = value.replace("{ Name = ", "");
            selected = selected.replace("}", "");

            window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "MaterialsList")' + '?selectedMatType=' + selected;
            //alert("val is:" + selected);
    }
```

**Update**

I changed the JavaScript to this Ajax call and that called my Controller HttpPost Index() function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(':radio[name="MatType"]').change(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/MaterialsList/Index',
                data: { selectedMatType: $(':radio[name="MatType"]:checked').val()},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('did it');
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Unfortunately the Controller is still being reloaded and I'm losing the state of the data selected into the Partial View #3 Telerik grid...

...any help would be much appreciated...

**Update #2**

This solution sucks but I don't know what else to do...

The goal is to retain the state of the datasource for a Telerik grid in Partial View #3.  The datasource is a ViewModel with a List of class objects.

Added Partial View #2 code and ActionResult from Controller.  There is no HttpPost Index function.  Every radio button change fires the ActionResult Index.  Every select event in Telerik grid fires ActionResult Index.

Pertinent Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string selectedMatType, string selectedMaterials, string projectMaterialsList)      
        {
            if (projectMaterialsList != null)
            {
                materialsListVM.ProjectMaterialsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectMaterialsListVM.ProjectMaterial>>(projectMaterialsList);
            }

            if (selectedMatType != null)
            {
                materialsListVM.SelectMaterialType(selectedMatType);
                materialsListVM.GetMaterials();
            }

            if (selectedMaterials != null)
            {
                string[] materialIds = selectedMaterials.Split(',');
                foreach (string id in materialIds)
                {
                    MoveToProjectMaterialsList(id, selectedMatType);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.ProjectMaterialsList = materialsListVM.ProjectMaterialsList;
            ViewBag.SelectedMatType = selectedMatType;
            return View(materialsListVM);
        }
```

Partial View #2 code:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.MaterialsListVM

<div>
    @if (ViewBag.SelectedMatType == "Cap Weld")
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CapWeld_Materials)
                            .Name("grid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Select().Width(40);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.MaterialId).Hidden();
                                columns.Bound(c => c.MaterialTypeName);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.PcsPartNum);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.ClientPartNum);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Type).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
                                columns.Bound(c => c.OuterDiameter).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
                                columns.Bound(c => c.WallThickness).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Specification).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Grade).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
                            })
                            .Events(ev => ev.Change("onChange"))
                            .Pageable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Scrollable()
                            .TableHtmlAttributes(new { width = "100%" })
                            //.HtmlAttributes(new { style="height:500px"})
                            .PersistSelection(true)
                            .Filterable()
                            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                            .Ajax()
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Model(m => m.Id(d => d.MaterialId))
                            )
        );
    }
</div>

@{
    var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var val = jss.Serialize(ViewBag.ProjectMaterialsList);
}


<script>
    function onChange(arg) {
        var selectedMatType = '@(ViewBag.SelectedMatType)';
        var projectMaterialsList = '@Html.Raw(val)';
        //var obj = $.parseJSON(val);
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var selectedMaterials = grid.selectedKeyNames().join(", ");
       // alert(selectedMaterials);
        @*$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedMatType: selectedMatType, selectedMaterials: selectedMaterials, projectMaterialsList: projectMaterialsList },
            dataType: "json",
            url: @Url.Action("Index", "MaterialsList")
        });*@

        window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "MaterialsList")' + '?selectedMatType=' + selectedMatType + '&selectedMaterials=' + selectedMaterials
            + '&projectMaterialsList=' + projectMaterialsList;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Had to back off of using Ajax.  The Ajax call was working to call the HttpPost version of the Index function but then the View was empty.

Comment: Got this working but I'm sure it is NOT the right way to do this.  I will edit above with an update under "Update #2" ...